# VBA rows for reconciliations

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am new VBA user trying to assemble a very basic trade reconciliation template. I seem to have the majority done, but I cant seem to work out the sorting behavior "such that" all stocks that are unmatched shown on separate row lines. As you can see I was able to get the sorting to work for the main portion of items that matched, but all the unmatched items just get pushed to the bottom. That is fine, but really they should be on separate rows to show visually that each line item is separately unmatched.

[image: recon image attached]

This is as far as I could get with my code. Separating out the rows with all unmatched items where say the stock name (A4 vs. H4) and also the quantity (E4 vs L4) are not matching all should be getting moved to their own line item - to visually confirm for the end reader there is a unmatch.

```
Sub Sample_Trade_Recon()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Tab 1 & Tab 2 Raw data pasted in. Do a prelim sort of the actual columns 
you want compare on the summary sheet'

Sheets("QT").Select Range("A3:G300").Select 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Clear 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A3:A300"), _ 
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B3:B300"), _ 
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C3:C300"), _ 
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D3:D300"), _ 
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E3:E300"), _ 
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F3:F300"), _ 
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G3:G300"), _ 
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal With 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort .SetRange Range("A3:G300") .Header = 
xlGuess .MatchCase = False .Orientation = xlTopToBottom .SortMethod = 
xlPinYin .Apply End With

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("A3:G300").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A3:A300"), 
_
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B3:B300"), 
_
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C3:C300"), 
_
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D3:D300"), 
_
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E3:E300"), 
_
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F3:F300"), 
_
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G3:G300"), 
_
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort
.SetRange Range("A3:G300")
.Header = xlGuess
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With


' Tab 1 Raw data columns you want compared '

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("A3:A40").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("A4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("B3:B40").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("B4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("C3:C40").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("C4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("D3:D40").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("D4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("E3:E40").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("E4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("F3:F40").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("F4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("G3:G40").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("G4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
' Tab 2 Raw data columns you want compared '

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("A3:A45").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("H4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("B3:B45").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("I4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("C3:C45").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("J4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("D3:D45").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("K4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("E3:E45").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("L4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("F3:F45").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("M4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("G3:G45").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("N4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
MsgBox ("Recon is assembled; please comment on all differences !")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So looks like im getting very close to the desired behavior. Only issue is its happening only once ?

Please see the updated code and let me know if anyone can assist with why its not repeating when the skip row is showing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS1CF.png)

```
Sub Sample_Trade_Recon()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



' Tab 1 & Tab 2 Raw data pasted in. Do a prelim sort of the actual columns 
you want compare on the summary sheet'


Sheets("QT").Select
Range("A3:G300").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A3:A300"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B3:B300"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C3:C300"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D3:D300"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E3:E300"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F3:F300"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G3:G300"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("QT").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A3:G300")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("A3:G300").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A3:A300"), 
_
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B3:B300"), 
_
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C3:C300"), 
_
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D3:D300"), 
_
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E3:E300"), 
_
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F3:F300"), 
_
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G3:G300"), 
_
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SSC").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A3:G300")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With





' Tab 1 Raw data columns you want compared '

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("A3:A300").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("A4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("B3:B300").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("B4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("C3:C300").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("C4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("D3:D300").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("D4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("E3:E300").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("E4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("F3:F300").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("F4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("QT").Select
Range("G3:G300").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("G4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues



' Tab 2 Raw data columns you want compared '

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("A3:A300").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("H4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("B3:B300").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("I4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("C3:C300").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("J4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("D3:D300").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("K4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("E3:E300").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("L4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("F3:F300").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("M4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Sheets("SSC").Select
Range("G3:G300").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Recon").Select
Range("N4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues




'Dynamic Sorting based on column total lengths'


Dim lastA, lastB, shortCol, rw As Integer

'Determine short column so we know when to stop
lastA = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
lastB = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("H:H"))
      If lastA > lastB Then _
      shortCol = 2 Else shortCol = 1



'Set First Check Row
rw = 4

nxtChk:

'Check Column A against Column H, Row by Row
'Insert cell at non-matching data
If Cells(rw, 26) <> "Keep" And shortCol = 2 Then


      Cells(rw, 8).Insert shift:=xlDown
      Cells(rw, 9).Insert shift:=xlDown
      Cells(rw, 10).Insert shift:=xlDown
      Cells(rw, 11).Insert shift:=xlDown
      Cells(rw, 12).Insert shift:=xlDown
      Cells(rw, 13).Insert shift:=xlDown
      Cells(rw, 14).Insert shift:=xlDown

Refresh all formulas in difference column so excel knows where to insert 
the skip row (based on formulas)'
Range("O4:Z4").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O4:Z300")


     Else


If Cells(rw, 26) <> "Keep" And shortCol = 1 Then


      Cells(rw, 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
      Cells(rw, 2).Insert shift:=xlDown
      Cells(rw, 3).Insert shift:=xlDown
      Cells(rw, 4).Insert shift:=xlDown
      Cells(rw, 5).Insert shift:=xlDown
      Cells(rw, 6).Insert shift:=xlDown
      Cells(rw, 7).Insert shift:=xlDown

'Refresh all formulas in difference column so excel knows where to insert 
the skip row (based on formulas)'
Range("O4:Z4").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O4:Z300")

End If



'If there is nothing left to check in the skiprow column , we're done
If Cells(rw, 26) = " " Then Exit Sub
'If not, increment Row counter and loop
rw = rw + 1

GoTo nxtChk


End If





Range("O4:Z4").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O4:Z300")



Application.ScreenUpdating = True




'Operations Team notices to review data presentation'

MsgBox ("Please insert comments into Column AA for all differences !")

MsgBox ("NOTE: If identifer data sorting is off slightly; then please fix by 
repasting the data grids on either side up/down a row as needed to realign 
properly. This often happens when Identifiers Repeat ")



End Sub
```